# How does StackOverflow handle cache invalidation?

Tags: discussion, technology, caching

I've always been impressed with StackOverflow's cache: it seems to strike a perfect balance between snappiness and sensibility.

Which of the half-dozen* cache invalidation strategies promoted by [Microsoft](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/caching/SQLInvalidation.aspx) does StackOverflow use? I personally would love to hear a 2-3 sentence summary from a member of the team, and I imagine it would be instructive to a lot of people building sites on the MSFT stack.

*Okay, maybe I exaggerate.

Comment: This question may be relevant to the question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110320/stack-overflow-db-performance-and-redis-cache

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One thing we do

- Key: the hash of the SQL, combined with a string name
- Value: the `List<int>` of ID numbers returned by the search

There's your key-value pair, and that is placed in `HttpRuntime.Cache`

Views take those list of IDs and hydrate the rest of the row / table values depending on what page they are on, etc.

We do both sliding cache (re-validated every time it is used) or fixed time expiration, depending on what is needed.

Comment: I thought you were using LINQ... are you getting the generated SQL somehow?

Comment: So, no explicit invalidation? Just expiration? I thought for sure the site used some kind of invalidation, but I guess I've just gotten lucky. Anyways, many thanks for the reply.

Comment: @WildJoe, you can get the SQL from your DataContext. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it uses one of the cache validation strategies that the MVC framework uses. Although this site was built when the MVC was in beta, so they may have their own solution.